# Почему в textedit, при открытии файла, выводится путь к файлу, а не содержимое файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt5, pyqt5

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QAction, QFileDialog, QApplication)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.statusBar()

        openFile = QAction(QIcon('open.png'), 'Open', self)
        openFile.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openFile.setStatusTip('Open new File')
        openFile.triggered.connect(self.showDialog)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(openFile)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('File dialog')
        self.show()

    def showDialog(self):
        dialogSelectFiles = QFileDialog()
        dialogSelectFiles.setFileMode(QFileDialog.ExistingFiles) 

        dialogSelectFiles.exec_()

        data = dialogSelectFiles.selectedFiles()
        self.textEdit.setText('\n'.join(data))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Вы ведь задавали подобный вопрос, разница только в количестве файлов. А выводит у вас список потому что вы список и запрашиваете используя `selectedFiles()`

Comment: @gil9red сейчас с другой вот проблемой столкнулся. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Чтобы вывести содержимое файла, нужно этот файл прочитать. Где в коде читается содержимое файла?

Comment: Потому что `QtWidgets.QFileDialog.selectedFiles()` - возвращает список строк, содержащих абсолютные пути выбранных файлов в диалоговом окне.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перебираете список файлов, считываете из них в переменную и ее отображаете в редакторе:

```
import traceback
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QAction, QFileDialog, QApplication, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print(text)
    QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    sys.exit()


sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.statusBar()

        openFile = QAction(QIcon('open.png'), 'Open', self)
        openFile.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openFile.setStatusTip('Open new File')
        openFile.triggered.connect(self.showDialog)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(openFile)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('File dialog')
        self.show()

    def showDialog(self):
        dialogSelectFiles = QFileDialog()
        dialogSelectFiles.setFileMode(QFileDialog.ExistingFiles)

        dialogSelectFiles.exec_()

        data = []
        for file_name in dialogSelectFiles.selectedFiles():
            with open(file_name, encoding='utf-8') as f:
                text = f.read()
                data.append(text)

        self.textEdit.setText('\n'.join(data))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: после "Открыть" файл, сразу закрывается окно.

Comment: @Иван, скорее всего несовпадение кодировки. Например, если открывать файл в кодировке, в которой он не является, то может произойти ошибка или будут кракозябры. Я вам предоставлю полное решение, которое покажет ошибку. Ответ обновлю. Попробуйте открыть созданные вами txt файлы -- с ними проблем не должно быть. А так, или открывайте в бинарном режиме или предоставьте возможность из интерфейса указать кодировку файла.